# Transfer posts from LiveJournal to Blogger

Tags: blogger, migrate-data, livejournal

I started off blogging using LiveJournal but I switched to Blogger as I like to do as much as possible inside the Google ecosystem.

Is there an easy way to transfer my LiveJournal posts to Blogger, while retaining the creation date of each post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I created a dummy WordPress blog, used their import tool to import the LiveJournal blog, and then used [wordpress2blogger](http://wordpress2blogger.appspot.com/) to transfer to Blogger.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Blog2Blog, as described [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4929837_import-livejournal-blogger.html)?

Comment: That looked good but unfortunately it appears that LiveJournal has changed its API and Blog2Blog hasn't been updated to match it.